# Error in the function ...can I pass input parameters in a function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is only a little piece of code... but the terminal give me an error "syntax error near token not expected "archive" ".
The functions in bash do not accept parameters like `function fun (hello) {`

```
function extractProcess (archive){
  mv $archive $WORK_DIR
  pathFile=${archive%/*} #Path input archive
  nameFile=$(ls $WORK_DIR)
  name=${archive%.*} #nameFile without exteension
  case $nameFile in
    *.tar.bz)   tar xjf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR          ;;
    *.tar.bz2)  tar xjf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR          ;;
    *.tar.gz)   tar xzf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR          ;;
    *.bz)       bunzip2 "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile"      ;;
    *.bz2)      bunzip2 "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile"      ;;
    *.gz)       gunzip -Ndk "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile"       ;;
    *.tar)      tar xf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR       ;;
    *.tbz)      tar xjf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR      ;;
    *.tbz2)     tar xjf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR      ;;
    *.tgz)      tar xzf "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -C $WORK_DIR      ;;
    *.zip)      unzip -qq "$WORK_DIR/$nameFile" -d $WORK_DIR        ;;
  esac
```

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) says: "Trying to declare parameters? Don't. Use () and refer to params as $1, $2.."

Comment: The rest of shellcheck's warnings (many of which are only displayed after more immediate problems are fixed) are also pertinent. See also [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Your title refers to "input parameters", but it's not clear what you mean by that phrase. Bash doesn't have anything it formally refers to by that term.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you cannot *declare* formal parameters. Instead, whatever arguments are passed when you call the function are available as positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc in the body.

```
# The parentheses are always empty, to signal a function definition.
# The function keyword is a non-standard extension and should be avoided.
extractProcess () {

    archive=$1
    ...
}
```

Comment: This function calls me sevre to be called in a for loop, and the index of this for loop is the parameter that I have to pass in input

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi, how/why do you think that makes this answer invalid? `$1`, in a function, is the first argument *passed to the function*; it no longer refers to the first argument passed to the script as a whole. Thus, you accept arguments in functions the same way you accept arguments in scripts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can not I pass an input parameter to the function? that then for example as in my case I recall inside the for and use parameter as the parameter of the for

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi, what do you mean "input parameter"? Do you mean a parameter that was passed positionally to the script? If you want to pass that through, do so explicitly: `extractProcess "$1" "$archive" "$workDir"` will pass the original `$1`, before the variables `archive` and `workDir`.

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi, ...or if you want to pass *all* of your script's parameters through to the function, you can of course use `"$@"` for that. If you call `yourFunction "$someVar" "$@"`, then inside the function `"$someVar"` will be `$1`, then the original `$1` will be `$2`, the original `$2` will be `$3`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in this way, invoke the extractProcess function and pass it as indicated by the index of the per, in this case $ f

for ext in ${EXTENSIONS[@]}
do
  ARCHIVES=$(find $d -name "*.$ext") #Inizialize archives
  for f in "${ARCHIVES[@]}"
  do
    extractProcess($f)
  done
done

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi It's just `extractProcess "$f"`; inside the body of `extractProcess`, `$1` refers to the value passed from `$f`.

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi, that code is inherently buggy -- you can't safely store a list of filenames in a string-type variable, since any character that can be in a string can also be in a filename (so there's no possible way to know with safety where one name ends and the next begins). See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and the "Actions" and "Complex Actions" sections of [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for alternate (safe) practices.

Comment: @AndreaGhezzi, ...let me reiterate the note in the comment on the question advising you to run your code through http://shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than trying to define them in the function declaration, use the `$` parameters:

```
function extractProcess (){
  archive=$1
  mv $archive $WORK_DIR
  pathFile=${archive%/*}
```

Comment: `function foo() {` merges ksh and POSIX sh function declaration forms into a result that's strictly compatible with neither of those predecessor shells. Use either `function foo {` for compatibility with ancient ksh, or `foo() {` with no preceding `function` for compliance with the POSIX sh standard (and thus compatibility with dash, ash, and all other POSIX-superset shells). See also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Also, please try to show correct quoting in your examples -- ie. `mv "$archive" "$WORK_DIR"` (or, even better, `mv -- "$archive" "$WORK_DIR"`, to support names that start with a dash).

Comment: This function calls me sevre to be called in a for loop, and the index of this for loop is the parameter that I have to pass in input

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, good points all.  I wrote this off-the-cuff (copy/paste) yesterday w/out thinking too much about quoting or using the `function` keyword...